# 404 not found when passing variable to route in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to run an ajax call, and i keep getting

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/books/rate/2 404 (Not Found)

So it gets the id well, but showing a 404 error.

**route.php**

```
Route::post('rate/{book_id}','BookController@rate')->name('rate');
```

**main.js**

```
$('#sub').submit(function(e){
    var owl = $(this).attr("data");
    var route = JSON.parse(owl);

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"rate/" + route.id,
            headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN':  $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
              }, 
            success:function(res){
               console.log("owls");
            }
       });

    event.preventDefault();

});
```

**controller**(book controller)

```
public function rate(Request $request, $book_id)
{
    $book = Book::find($book_id);
    $rating = $book->ratings()->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->first();

    if(is_null($rating)){
        $ratings = new Rating();
        $ratings->rating =  $request['rating'];
        $ratings->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $book->ratings()->save($ratings);
        return json_encode($book);
    }
    else{
        return redirect()->back()->with("status", "You already left a review");
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="sub" data= "{{ $book }}">
   {!! csrf_field() !!}
   <div id="rateYo" data-rateyo-rating="{{  $book->userSumRating or 0}}"> ></div>
   <input name="rating" value='{{  $book->userSumRating  or 0 }}' type="hidden" id="val">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-2">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: can you add your controller code in question ?

Comment: yes once sec rkj

Comment: ok just updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using ajax post so instead redirect use json response like this

```
public function rate(Request $request, $book_id)
{
    $book = Book::find($book_id);
    $rating = $book->ratings()->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->first();

    if(is_null($rating)){
        $ratings = new Rating();
        $ratings->rating =  $request['rating'];
        $ratings->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $book->ratings()->save($ratings);
        return json_encode($book);
    }
    else{
       return response()->json(['status' => "You already left a review"]);
    }
}
```

Add try this javascript code

```
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"http://127.0.0.1:8000/rate/" + route.id,
        headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN':  $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          },
        data:{rating: $('#val').val()},
        success:function(res){
           console.log("owls");
        }
});
```

Comment: let me try this out.

Comment: i still get `jquery.min.js:2 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/books/rate/2 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: did you check in which condition you are getting this ? i mean in if case or else case ?

Comment: it doesn't show, it  just says 404 not found. so it gives no references to the back end. i think it has something to do csrf_token

Comment: then try adding `_token` in your ajax post data

Comment: is your project in `books` folder ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176919/discussion-between-rkj-and-barnowl).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a change in javascript like below

```
$('#sub').submit(function(e){
      var owl = $(this).attr("data");
      var route = JSON.parse(owl);



         $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"http://127.0.0.1:8000/rate/" + route.id,
            headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN':  $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
              }, 
            success:function(res){
               console.log("owls");
            }
         });

      event.preventDefault();


   });
```

This is because in your URL you are getting books before rate/{rate_id} thats why it is showing error of 404 page not found!

Comment: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/books/%7B%7Burl('rate/')%7D%7D2 404 (Not Found)'

Comment: this brings me closer to the solution, however

Comment: `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'rating' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `ratings` (`rating`, `user_id`, `rateable_type`, `rateable_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (, 1, App\Book, 2, 2018-07-28 05:18:24, 2018-07-28 05:18:24))"
trace
:
[{,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…},…]`

Answer (score -1):

Just Use It Like This :-

```
$.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"{{url('rate/')}}" + route.id,
            headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN':  {{ csrf_token() }}
              }, 
            success:function(res){
               console.log("owls");
            }
     });
```